# Spring RestTemplate added, Exception on launch to Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, maven, resttemplate

I've added code to implement a RestTemplate Client to my Spring MVC project (Eclipse, Maven, Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE). Everything builds and when I launch to Tomcat7, I get the output below. Is it possibly a Spring artifact I'm missing in the pom.xml? I've got

- spring-webmvc (excluding commons-logging)
- spring-oxm
- spring-security-web
- spring-security-config
- spring-tx
- spring-aop
- spring-orm
- spring-test
- apache httpclient (excluding commons-logging).

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
    .
    .
    nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadC lass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadC lass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
... 39 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need apache http components:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```